# Optimizing square matrix multiplication with std::thread

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to implement matrix multiplying with std::thread in C++.
Currently, my kernel code looks like

```
void multiply(const int* a, const int* b, int* c, int rowLength, int start) {
        for (auto i = start; i < rowLength; i += threadCount) {
                const auto rowI = i * rowLength;
                for (auto j = 0; j < rowLength; j++) {
                        auto result = 0;
                        const auto rowJ = j * rowLength;
                        for (auto k = 0; k < rowLength; k++) {
                                result += a[rowI + k] * b[rowJ + k];
                        }
                        c[rowI + j] = result;
                }
        }
}
```

As you see, I'm multiplying matrix A with already transposed matrix B (it's done during input). Currently, I'm trying to use one-dimension approach. Is there any optimizations that can I make with my current code?

Comment: You could actually use threading as your title claims, but your code doesn't actually do. Locality is going to play a big part too. Also, plan wisely, because threading likely isn't going to help unless these matrices are *massive* (a detail you also didn't mention).

Comment: Yes, the matrices are pretty massive. I forgot to mention that that function is called with std::thread(), so there is threading (for example, I use N threads so it's called in loop i=0...N where i is start variable. Then it shift with threadCount (in above code it's second line).

Comment: The outer loop is going to degrade the ability of the hardware prefetch to help you as it's non-unit stride.  You're better off stripmining threadCount blocks of size rowLength/threadCount.  Since this is an integer matrix-matrix multiply, most modern chips don't give you the multi-issue or triad instructions (i.e. muladd) so don't expect to see anything near the FLOP peak rating of the chip.  What percent of integer peak are you getting?  Can the problem be cast as a float or double?  What processor are you targetting?  What does the cache hierarchy look like?